# Unable to run local Celery worker, no module named myapp

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a Django 1.11 project, with Celery 3.1.25, laid out like:

```
env
myproject
    myapp
    myotherapp
    settings
         settings.py
    __init__.py
    celery_init.py
```

My `__init__.py` contains:

```
from .celery_init import app as celery_app
```

and my `celery_init.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import sys
import traceback

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('myproject')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

When I go to start a local Celery worker for development testing, with:

```
env/bin/celery worker -A myproject -l info -n sr@%h -Q somequeue
```

it fails with the exception:

```
ImportError: No module named myapp
```

What's causing this? I assume it's some path problem and not being able to properly load my project's settings, but I don't see the problem with my configuration. I just upgraded to Django 1.11, and these settings were working fine in the prior version. What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding print statements at the end of my `celery_init.py`, to ensure it's loading everything, and every line completes without error.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: Run the command from inside myproject folder,(project level folder not settings level), make sure virtual env is activated, if the application is running within one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a sys.path issue in combination with a lack of initializing Django. The working `celery_init.py` looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import sys

from celery import Celery
import django

app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.settings')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../myproject')))
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Comment: thks it worked for me I gave three days on it after that with the help of original document of celery and your code my problem has been resolved...

Comment: @Cerin this is very interesting as I'm facing a similar situation, are you running this instance of Celery "detached" from Django, and that's why you're wanting to call `django.setup()` inside this file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I solved putting the --workdir parameter located to the directory where manage.py is in.
I'm now using celery 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I was following a tutorial (I'm new to celery), and in it the command to run the 'task' app was:

```
celery -A worker some_app -l info
```

but that didn't work for me; 
only this worked (reversing the order of some_app and worker)

```
celery -A some_app worker -l info
```

It seems like the second code makes more sense, but I'm not sure why the first code worked for the guy in the tutorial but not me...unless that worked in an older version and not in the version that I have.